# longer text in a selectBoxIt drop-down list is not visible (if chosen)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-select, selectboxit

I have a drop-down list using selectBoxIt. if an Option, is longer than width of the drop down menu, the text will be disappear if chosen.I couldn't find the solution on the internet.

following 2 pictures show the problem:

if the text is shorter than the width of menu, everything is fine
[image]

if the text is longer, menu shows empty
[image]

here is how i initialize selectBoxIt

```
    $(function() {
        var selectBox = $("select").selectBoxIt({ autoWidth: false });
    });
```

My selectBoxIt has version v3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links:

https://jsfiddle.net/ZTs42/2/

```
$(function(){

            $("#testselectset").selectBoxIt({
                theme: "default",
                defaultText: "Make a selection...",
                autoWidth: false
            });
            $("#testselectset").change(function(){
                alert("You selected: "+this.value+" from the Selectboxit plugin");
            });

        });
```

https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/issues/129